# Internal Table implementation in Hyperledger Fabric Chaincode

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I am working with fabric chaincodes and have implemented the table concepts being provided to store data since blockchain does not allow modification or deletion, i am eager to know the internal implementation of the table format. Is there any documentation for that if yes please suggest or if anyone knows and can explain.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Tables are implemented using Protocol Buffers.
You can have a look at file [table.pb.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/core/chaincode/shim/table.pb.go). This file is auto-generated file by using proto message definitions in [table.proto](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/core/chaincode/shim/table.proto) .

On top of this, chaincode API provides functions like `CreateTable`, `GetTable`, `DeleteTable`, `GetRow`, `GetRows`, `InsertRow` which you might be using in your chaincode.

Functions like `CreateTable`, `InsertRow`, `DeleteTable` which are supposed to do data modification internally use `PutState` API to write the bytevalues to ledger. `PutState` marshals a struct defined in file `table.pb.go` into bytes and stores into ledger.

Similarly functions like `GetRow`, `GetRows`, `GetTable` which are supposed to query data, internally use `GetState` API to read the bytevalues from ledger. `GetState` API finds the value from ledger in bytes and then unmarshals the byte value into structs.

Effectively you get to interact with Go structs without caring how internally the table is stored.